# porque VisualStudio no permite subir cambios al repositorio github?

Tags: github, vs2017

estoy usando VisualStudio Comunity 2017 en Window7 y descargué ahí un proyecto de que tengo en github, cabe mencionar que el proyecto lo hice igualmente en VS2017 pero x86. Intenté cerrar sesion github desde el TeamExplorer y volverme a loguear pero me pidió loguearme en el explorador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Posteriorme seguí la recomendación de un post que menciona modificar VS quitando Github;desinstalé github y borré la carpeta de git dentro de IDE/CommondExtension/TeamExplorer/... .fuí a la pagina de git a descargar de nuevo la versión para Windows y Volví a conectarme al repositorio en VS, parecía que todo estaba bien, sin embargo al tratar de confirmar mis cambios hay una carpeta que no pude excluir y aparenta estar protejido el resto del código pero en realidad no se subió al repo en internet

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No se si tenga que ver que al descargar el proyecto lo hice en un diferente al predeterminado.
Ahora si en el team explorer le doy a insertar rama manda que no puede insertarla porque la rama actual está detras de la rama principal o algo similar en la salida de consola

Creo se complicó un poco al probar la opción de Preparar cambios en el link de acciones de TeamExplorer,luego intenté agregar esos archivos al gitignore pero no fué suficiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no entiendo para que tapas palabras que ni siqueira son inicio de sesion y password mas la direccion url, son tablas u objetos que tu llamas.

Comment: se agrego la palabra lock en tu archivo, quitala. una vez me paso pero no recuerdo bien

Comment: @Ramiro Barone , no creo q sea relevante ver el nombre de mis rutas(por politicas de la empresa ocultamos cualquier indicio de información interna)..

Comment: respecto al db.lock si lo elimino lo vuelve a crear, aun abriendo el VS como administrador, tal vez tenga que ver con que no obtuve cambios antes de intentar protejer o hacer un check out

Comment: me parece que tu proyecto le puede estar faltando el .gitignore porque es una carpeta que no deberia tener en cuenta para hacer commit y push.